# Unexpected EXC_BAD_ACCESS on scrolling many times UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Hello everyone I have a big problem.I am developing an iPad app. In this I have reused table view cells in UITableView. Earlier I didn’t reuse the cells and it was working but very slow. To improve performance I have rused cells now it is very fast but when I scroll many times or with speed then *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* occurred with following message:

```
-[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5aba7b0
```

I found the actual IBOutlet which being released . It is UIImageView . Before it same problem was with a UIButton in the cell. I declared it with retain property then it was resolved. Now if I declare imageview retain it works but..prob now is that I need 2 type of imageViews according to position of cell odd or even. Now it shows same imageviews in ..continue 3,2,4..cells not fixed. I am strugling with problem please help following the code: One more thing I loading 3 type of cells so I have stored cellIdientifier in Defect object

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BaseTableDelegate.h"

@interface AssignResponsibilityTableDelegate : BaseTableDelegate {

//Assign Responsibility Table cell IBOutlet
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *assignResponsibilityTableCustomCell;
IBOutlet UIButton *assignResCellViewButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *assignResCellNoteButton;
IBOutlet UILabel *assignREsCellDetailLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *assignResImageView;
IBOutlet UILabel *assignREsCellElementlabel;

//Trade
IBOutlet UIView *tradeSpinnerBackgroundView;    
IBOutlet UITextView *tradeTextView;    
IBOutlet UITextView *tradeSelectedNameTextView;    
IBOutlet UIButton *tradeSpinnerButton;

//SubContractor
IBOutlet UIView *subcontractorSpinnerView;    
IBOutlet UITextView *subContractorTextView;
IBOutlet UITextView *subContractorSelectedNameTextView;    
IBOutlet UIButton *subContractorSpinnerButton;

UIImage* greenLenseImage;
UIImage* lenceImage;
UIImage* noteExistImage;
UIImage* noteNotExistImage;

NSMutableArray* assignDefects;

//    int cellHeight;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextView *subContractorSelectedNameTextView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextView *tradeSelectedNameTextView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIButton *tradeSpinnerButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *tradeSpinnerBackgroundView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *subcontractorSpinnerView;

//Assign Responsibility Table Cell Click Action
- (IBAction)tradeContractorButtonClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)subContractorButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

Following is the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Defect* defect=nil;

    if(defects && [defects count]>0){

        defect=[defects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:defect.cellIdientifier];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.reuseIdentifier);

    int row = [indexPath row];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSLog(@"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++888Button=%@",assignResCellViewButton);
        NSLog(@"Button=%@",subContractorSpinnerButton);
        NSLog(@"Button=%@",tradeSpinnerButton);
        NSLog(@"Button=%@",assignResCellNoteButton);

   NSLog(@"assignResponsibilityTableCustomCell=%@",assignResponsibilityTableCustomCell);
         NSLog(@"assignResCellViewButton=%@",assignResCellViewButton);
         NSLog(@"assignResCellNoteButton=%@",assignResCellNoteButton);
         NSLog(@"tradeSpinnerButton=%@",tradeSpinnerButton);
         NSLog(@"subContractorSpinnerButton=%@",subContractorSpinnerButton);
         NSLog(@"assignREsCellElementlabel=%@",assignREsCellElementlabel);
         NSLog(@"assignREsCellDetailLabel=%@",assignREsCellDetailLabel);
         NSLog(@"assignResImageView=%@",assignResImageView);
         NSLog(@"tradeTextView=%@",tradeTextView);
         NSLog(@"subContractorTextView=%@",subContractorTextView);
         NSLog(@"tradeSelectedNameTextView=%@",tradeSelectedNameTextView);

       NSLog(@"subContractorSelectedNameTextView=%@",subContractorSelectedNameTextView);
         NSLog(@"tradeSpinnerBackgroundView=%@",tradeSpinnerBackgroundView);
         NSLog(@"subcontractorSpinnerView=%@",subcontractorSpinnerView);
                NSLog(@"++++++++++++++++++++999Button=%@",statusButton);

        //Load Nib as per Text Length
        [self getCellNibName:defect];

        //[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AssignResponsibilityCellItem" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=assignResponsibilityTableCustomCell;
        assignResCellViewButton.tag=VIEW_BUTTON_TAG;
        assignResCellNoteButton.tag=NOTE_BUTTON_TAG;
        tradeSpinnerButton.tag=TRADE_SPINNER_BUTTON_TAG;
        subContractorSpinnerButton.tag=SUBCONTRACTOR_BUTTON_TAG;
        assignREsCellElementlabel.tag=ELEMENT_LABEL_TAG;
        assignREsCellDetailLabel.tag=DETAIL_LABEL_TAG;
        assignResImageView.tag=BG_IMAGEVIEW_TAG;
        tradeTextView.tag=TRADE_TEXTVIEW_TAG;
        subContractorTextView.tag=SUBCONTRACTOR_TEXTVIEW_TAG;
        tradeSelectedNameTextView.tag=TRADE_NAME_TEXTVIEW_TAG;
        subContractorSelectedNameTextView.tag=SUBCONTRACTOR_NAME_TEXTVIEW_TAG;
        tradeSpinnerBackgroundView.tag=133;
        subcontractorSpinnerView.tag=134;
    }

    //SetTag

    assignREsCellElementlabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:ELEMENT_LABEL_TAG];
    assignResCellViewButton=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:VIEW_BUTTON_TAG];
    assignResCellNoteButton=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:NOTE_BUTTON_TAG];
    assignREsCellDetailLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:DETAIL_LABEL_TAG];
    tradeSpinnerButton=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:TRADE_SPINNER_BUTTON_TAG];
    subContractorSpinnerButton=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:SUBCONTRACTOR_BUTTON_TAG];
    subContractorTextView=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:SUBCONTRACTOR_TEXTVIEW_TAG];
    assignResImageView=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:BG_IMAGEVIEW_TAG];
    tradeTextView=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:TRADE_TEXTVIEW_TAG];
    subContractorSelectedNameTextView=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:SUBCONTRACTOR_NAME_TEXTVIEW_TAG];
    tradeSelectedNameTextView=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:TRADE_NAME_TEXTVIEW_TAG];
    tradeSpinnerBackgroundView=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:133];
    subcontractorSpinnerView=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:134];
    //Set Text
    assignREsCellElementlabel.text=defect.defectElement.name;
    assignREsCellDetailLabel.text=defect.defectItem.name;
    //set viewButton image on the basis of defectPhoto availability





    assignResCellViewButton.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    assignResCellNoteButton.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    if(defect.defectPhoto && defect.defectPhoto.location && [StringUtil isValid:defect.defectPhoto.location]){

        [assignResCellViewButton setImage:greenLenseImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else{
        [assignResCellViewButton setImage:lenceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }


    //set note button image on the basis of comment availability

    if (defect.hasComments){
        [assignResCellNoteButton setImage:noteExistImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {
        [assignResCellNoteButton setImage:noteNotExistImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }


    defect.tradeTextView=tradeTextView;

    defect.subContractorTextView=subContractorTextView;

    //Show Trade
    [self decideTradeToBePlaced:defect :row];

    //Show SubContractor
    [self decideSubContractorToBePlaced:defect :row];
    tradeSpinnerButton.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    subContractorSpinnerButton.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    //subContractorSpinnerButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    //Set Cell Background(alternate white and gray)

   // defect.tableCell= assignResponsibilityTableCustomCell;

    if(indexPath.row % 2 ==0){

        [assignResImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    }else{

        [assignResImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a memory allocation/deallocation problem.

Profile your app using Instruments and choose the 'Zombies' instrument. This will allow you to identify exactly where this misuse of memory is taking place.

In addition, Instruments will allow you to see the complete retain/release cycle for the objects in question - typically it's pretty simple to track these down once you've got this data.

If you're still needing some more help, be sure to watch WWDC 2012 session 409 on 'Learning Instruments'.